# Why Julia Distribution package can't work with integer?

Tags: statistics, distribution, julia

It's possible to create Multivariate Distribution with:

```
using Distributions
rand(MvNormal([1, 1.], [1 .5; .5 1]), 2)
```

But it wouldn't work with integers:

```
using Distributions
rand(MvNormal([1, 1], [1 .5; .5 1]), 2)
```

**Why?**

P.S. The second example would throw an error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Distributions.MvNormal{Cov<:PDMats.AbstractPDMat{T<:AbstractFloat},Mean<:Union{Array{Float64,1},Distributions.ZeroVector{Float64}}}}, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Float64,2})
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Distributions.MvNormal{Cov<:PDMats.AbstractPDMat{T<:AbstractFloat},Mean<:Union{Array{Float64,1},Distributions.ZeroVector{Float64}}}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  Distributions.MvNormal(!Matched::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,2})
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert{T}(::Type{T}, !Matched::T)
  ...
while loading In[113], in expression starting on line 2

 in call at essentials.jl:57
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Julia, the numbers `1` and `1.0` are very different things.  The first is an `Integer` type, and the second is a `FloatingPoint` type.  So `[1, 1]` is an array of integers, whereas `[1.0, 1.0]` is an array of floating point numbers.

That error message tells you exactly why it didn't work, but it can be a little tough to parse with all the type parameters.

A MethodError means that it couldn't find a method with the matching argument types.  It's failing at a call to `convert(MvNormal{…}, ::Vector{Int}, ::Matrix{Float64}`. You didn't write a call to convert, though, so it must be happening within a library.  But the message goes on to say that *this might have occurred from a call to the constructor*.  That is, it couldn't match a constructor of the form `MvNormal{…}(::Vector{Int}, ::Matrix{Float64})`, so it fell back to a builtin method that tries to convert the arguments to the type instead of constructing it.  That is exactly what you wrote!  That method doesn't exist.

The message then gives you the closest matching method: `MvNormal(::Vector{Float64}, ::Matrix{Float64)`, and it even highlights the argument that didn't match with `!Matched`.

So, why doesn't it work?  Because nobody has written a constructor that allows a vector of integers. But why not? In Julia, Integers and FloatingPoint numbers behave very differently, so it's common to only support one if the other doesn't particularly make sense.  Unlike some other languages, you need to be aware of the difference between `1` and `1.0`.